# Visiting Romania and Croatia in one trip?

Tags: visas, romania, croatia

I'm visiting Romania and Croatia in one single trip. I'll stay in Romania for 14 days and Croatia for 7 days. Is it possible to use the Croatia short-stay visa for Romania as well? The Romania visa website says that a short-stay Croatia is sufficient to enter Romania, but my first entry is Romania.